# Camera feed frame_id

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, ubuntu, camera, frame-id

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Very new to ROS but I have set up a CSI camera with ROS melodic, running on ubuntu 18.04 (On jetson nano). And I am trying to overlay a pointcloud on it in rviz, however the camera visualization doesn't work as I'd expect. I am getting a For frame [/cam_frame]: Frame [/cam_frame] does not exist. The camera info and topic are recieved and OK and the image visulization works fine.

As far as I could understand I have to add some information to each frame to make this work? How would i do this?

Edit: just saw that the rviz Camera display requires calibration information, while the Image display does not. Going to test with calibration set.

Edit2: Still no luck after calibrating

Edit3: As far as I understood I am going to have to use the SetCameraInfo service to add the data.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367346/camera-feed-frame_id/) by [Y009](https://answers.ros.org/users/65031/y009/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am getting a For frame [/cam_frame]: Frame [/cam_frame] does not exist.

this implies the `sensor_msgs/Image` messages have their `header.frame_id` set to `cam_frame`, but that TF frame is actually not broadcast by anything.

The Camera display shows "the world" of RViz rendered from a specific viewpoint. To be able to do that, it must "know" where objects and the camera frame are. For this it uses TF. If you specify `cam_frame` as the `frame_id` (== TF frame), but that frame is not broadcast by anyone, RViz cannot resolve the location of the viewpoint from which to render objects.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Y009](https://answers.ros.org/users/65031/y009/) on 2020-12-13**:
thank you, got it working